Auth with supabase in nextjs
I'm trying to learn next js, but I don't understand how this works:
I have my navbar component where I call this function:
export default async function Navbar() {
  const supabase = createClient()

  const {
    data: { user },
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser()

  return (
    <div className="w-full">
      <nav className="w-full flex justify-center border-b border-b-foreground/10 h-16">
        <div className="w-full max-w-4xl flex justify-between items-center p-3 text-sm">
          <Link href={"/"}>Home</Link>
          <div>
            { user ?  
            ( 
              <>
              <Link href={"/account"}>Account</Link>
            <form action="/auth/signout" method="post">
              <button className="button block" type="submit">
                Sign out
              </button>
            </form></>) : 
            ( <Link href={"/login"}>Login</Link>)}
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  )
}

Then I have these links to home and account. So my question is, since it is a server component, do I need to make a call to supabase every time I go to home or account with it? Then, if I need to get the user in another component, do I need to make the same function?
Or should I create a context and just use it where I need it?
I want to see if someone can help understand something

does this answer your question
